# Flask Variable isn't transferring to the next page

Tags: python, flask

I am having problem with flask. Actually it is a Simple RNN hands oh project in which I am taking two strings from the user and predicting the sum of both strings taken by the user by using Simple RNN model.

But here I just checked to take two numbers from the user and add them directly without passing them to my model, after converting into integer just to make sure that it is moving to the result page and showing me the results. But the problem is that it is not moving to the next page which is result page.
When I am passing these two strings to my model it is also not moving to the next page.

This is my Flask Script code:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)


# load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)


# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights('model.h5')
print('Loaded model from disk')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/result', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    first_num = request.form['num_one']
    second_num = request.form['num_two']
    input1 = (first_num + '+' + second_num)
    output = int(first_num) + int(second_num)
    return render_template('result.html', Input=input1, Output=output, Predicted=output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my index code in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Recurrent Neural Network</title>
        <style>
            *{
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Simple Recurrent Neural Network</h1>    
        <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="POST">
            <label for="numOne">First Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="num_one" name="one">
            <br>
            <label for="w_class">Second Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="num_two" name="two">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my result file code in html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
       <h1> Predictions </h1>
       <form class=class="form-userDetails, action="/userDetails", method="POST">
            Input: {{ Input }}
            Output: {{ Output }}
            Predicted: {{ Predicted }}
    </br>
</form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Where did I make mistake?

Comment: Your form's action is specified as the index page, not the result page.

Comment: @jasonharper it workd when I change my form's action index to result , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the context/data in form of dictionary so that it can be used in the template.

Using a dictionary to pass the context:

```
return render_template('result.html', {'Input': input1,
                                       'Output': output, 
                                       'Predicted': output})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did same but still it is not moving to the result page

Comment: @AliHyder Also there is missing double quote in result.html template, it might be causing problem in the rendering.
at line <form class=class="form-userDetails", action="/userDetails", method="POST">